# Optimistic Lock

Tags: java, jpa, optimistic-locking

I would like to take a doubt on the optimistic lock,

Is there any way to tell to user 1 while changing a form that another user 2 already changed the same form (saved), without having to wait user 1 finish all your change and then know that the record has been changed by user 2?

Any example how to do this?

Comment: What gui technology? Anyway, you can usually/always have some kind of polling that reads the version indicator and displays updates. There might be some better approaches like websockets that produce less server load.

Comment: lets say that gui tech is primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think user1 have to try saving to know that the record has changed with JPA technology. 
But you can make a custom development to check record update and records selected for edit and send alert with websockets primefaces notify but it's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `UpdatePolicy` to `VERSION_REQUIRED`, you must use the `DocumentDescriptor` versions of the `write()` (when modifying a document) and `delete()` methods. If the change identifier has not changed, the write or delete operation succeeds. If someone else has changed the document so that a new version has been created, the operation fails by throwing an exception.

Source:  [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_44266)